# Replace the last occurrence of a field in a csv

Tags: regex, bash, csv, awk, sed

I have a csv file like this

```
 KEY,F1,F2,STEP,LAST_OCCURRENCE
 100.101,a,b,STEP_1,<empty>
 100.102,c,d,STEP_1,<empty>
 100.103,e,f,STEP_1,<empty>
 100.101,g,h,STEP_1,<empty>
 100.103,i,j,STEP_1,<empty>
 100.101,g,h,STEP_2,<empty>
 100.103,i,j,STEP_2,<empty>
```

I am able to change the final field to whatever is easiest to parse so it can be considered as either blank i.e `,\n` or containing the word `<empty>` as above.

From this file I have to replace "LAST_OCCURRENCE" field matching with last occurrence of [ KEY + STEP ] value with a boolean value (indicating that it's the last value for the tuple).

The expected result is this one:

```
 KEY,F1,F2,STEP,LAST_OCCURRENCE
 100.101,a,b,STEP_1,false
 100.102,c,d,STEP_1,true     #Last 100.102 for STEP_1
 100.103,e,f,STEP_1,false
 100.101,g,h,STEP_1,true     #Last 100.101 for STEP_1
 100.103,i,j,STEP_1,true     #Last 100.103 for STEP_1
 100.101,g,h,STEP_2,true     #Last 100.101 for STEP_2
 100.103,i,j,STEP_2,true     #Last 100.103 for STEP_2
```

Which is the fastest approach?
Would be possible to do it with a sed script or would be better to post-process the input file with another (perl? php?) script?

Comment: Does it actually say empty, or it it just empty ?

Comment: As the script that creates the source file is ongoing to be completed, this is something that I can decide. On other hands I can decide to store "(...),<empty>\n" string or simply "(...),\n" whatever it would be most convenient to parse.

Comment: `Which is the fastest approach?` - fastest to write or fastest to execute? You have a couple of potential solutions now that I suspect both took about the same length of time to write and you could test their execution speed with `time` if that's what you care about.

Comment: Right question! Fastest to execute. No doubt about it as this script has to be applied on a very huge number of text files for an amount of ~1.2 Tb of data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `tac` and `awk`:

```
tac file |
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} $1 != "KEY"{$NF = (seen[$1,$4]++) ? "false" : "true"} 1' |
tac
```

After listing the file in reverse order using `tac`, we use an associative array `seen` with composite key as `$1,$4` to figure out first occurrence of each composite key. Finally we do `tac` to get the file back in original order.

**Output:**

```
KEY,F1,F2,STEP,LAST_OCCURRENCE
100.101,a,b,STEP_1,false
100.102,c,d,STEP_1,true
100.103,e,f,STEP_1,false
100.101,g,h,STEP_1,true
100.103,i,j,STEP_1,true
100.101,g,h,STEP_2,true
100.103,i,j,STEP_2,true
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} NR==FNR{last[$1,$4]=NR;next} FNR>1{$NF=(FNR==last[$1,$4] ? "true" : "false")} 1' file file
 KEY,F1,F2,STEP,LAST_OCCURRENCE
 100.101,a,b,STEP_1,false
 100.102,c,d,STEP_1,true
 100.103,e,f,STEP_1,false
 100.101,g,h,STEP_1,true
 100.103,i,j,STEP_1,true
 100.101,g,h,STEP_2,true
 100.103,i,j,STEP_2,true
```